# llamada de funcion desde mysql # 1305

Tags: mysql, sql, function

Muy buenas tengo un error a continuación lo mencionare:
Hago la llamada a mi función y me sale ese error y mi funcion retorna un `INT`:

```
SELECT fn_VerificarCaracter("JuanPablo88","123456789");
```

El error que me sale es:

> #1305 - FUNCTION plataforma_systemeinformarketdigital._Usuario does not exist

¿Alguien tiene idea el por que me sale ese error?

Comment: Puede que haya elgun error en la función, de aquí que en el error ponga FUNCTION

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS ESTIMADO